# CSS Button styling

Tags: html, css

I'm still new in CSS, sorry for the long post. I have the following code

```
<style type="text/css">

.btn {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    background: url(images/btn_left.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.btn a{
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/btn_stretch.png) repeat-x left top;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn span {
    background: url(images/btn_right.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;

}
.btn_addtocart { background-color: green; }
.btn_checkout { background-color: red; }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="btn btn_addtocart"><a href="#">Add to Cart</a><span></span></div>

<div class="btn btn_checkout"><a href="#">Check Out</a><span></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to center each button in the middle of the page (horizontal alignment), how can I accomplish that? I tried playing with the padding and the margin but it messes my background image.

**Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtXYY/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try margin auto, text-align center, fixed width for middle part..
oh ..and get rid of the float, and dont forget the ';'

**edit** code..

```
.btn {
    clear: both;
    background: url(images/btn_left.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
.btn a {
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/btn_stretch.png) repeat-x left top;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn span {
    background: url(images/btn_right.png) no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
.btn_addtocart { background-color: green; }
.btn_checkout { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: looks perfect without the images but when i add the images it gets messed up, thanks though, helped me get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can `text-align:center` the links inside the divs (which are block-level elements) to center them inside their containers but you will have to make a couple of tweaks. Try this:

```
.btn {
    clear: both;
    background: url(images/btn_left.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn a {
    height: 40px;
    background: url(images/btn_stretch.png) repeat-x left top;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn span {
    background: url(images/btn_right.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;

}
.btn_addtocart a { background-color: green; }
.btn_checkout a { background-color: red; }
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/UtXYY/1/

Comment: looks perfect without the images but when i add the images it gets messed up, thanks though, helped me get the correct answer.

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to post the correct answer to your question, this is a community-run forum where people come for help, your solution might help someone else. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can do

```
.btn {
    display: block
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

By default a button is an inline element, so margins will no work. Setting display to block, will make it act like a

```
div.btnParent {
    text-align:center
}
```

The other method is to have the button's containing element text-align center. The may not necessarily always work, as there may be more content in this container that you do not want to be centered.

Comment: "By default a button is an inline element" - well, a button is typically a form INPUT tag. But in the example above it's an anchor tag, which, yes, is by default inline.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully see from your code snippet but to centre somthing in the middle of its parent, you need to set its margin to auto.

```
margin: auto
```

and its width

```
width: 100px:
```

**EDIT:**
Also remove any `float:` styles you have on the element.